# How to make visible my web server by android mobile

Tags: android, webserver, port, router, forwarding

I have a web server running on a mac laptop. This laptop is connected to the network by my android smartphone (which receives the network by mobile operator). I would like to make visible my web server from outside, so I installed a port fowarding application on my smarthone and associated its port 8080 to the port of my laptop 80.
Then I found the IP address of my mobile device by the site http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and I tried to connect by using as URL mobile.ip:8080. The connaction failed. So could anybody tell me where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Open a browser on your phone and type: http: // yourmacip /

Comment: I need to connect on my mac web server by another machine which is not on the network of my phone.